# Forms user entry to append form action

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to append the form action with what the user puts in the text box and having some problems, could someone help me out of this jam?

```
 <form action="http://wfbscd13.cadence.com/cgi-bin/motd.cgi?msg=1&cmd=replace&text=" method="get">
     <label for="mestext1"></label>
     <input type="text" size="100" maxlength="80">
     <input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Replace">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, for some reason, you need your `action` to be hardcoded:

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://wfbscd13.cadence.com/cgi-bin/motd.cgi?msg=1&cmd=replace&text=" method="get">
    <label for="mestext1"></label>
    <input type="text" id="mestext1" size="100" maxlength="80">
    <input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" value="Replace" onclick="submitForm();">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm()
{
    var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
    myForm.action = myForm.action + document.getElementById("mestext1").value;
    myForm.submit();
}
</script>
```

This is not the right way to do it though. You should be adding inputs named `msg` and `cmd` and hide them if needed. Then your code will look like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://wfbscd13.cadence.com/cgi-bin/motd.cgi" method="get">
    <label for="mestext1"></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="msg" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="replace">
    <input type="text" name="mestext1" id="mestext1" size="100" maxlength="80">
    <input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Replace">
</form>
```

Comment: I thought there was an easier way, just using html... but this makes perfect sense